# Sequelize query returns no child even though they exist

Tags: sequelize.js

I can't seem to get this to work.

I have two tables, AnalyticsSession and AnalyticsEvent and have tried to associate them.

When I query to get each Session and include the Events it works but the array is empty.

I wonder if I have the relationship correct?

The session

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class AnalyticsSession extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      AnalyticsSession.hasMany(models.AnalyticsEvent, {
        foreignKey: "id",
      });
    }
  }
  AnalyticsSession.init(
    {
      id: {
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
      },     
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "AnalyticsSession",
    }
  );
  return AnalyticsSession;
};
```

The event

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class AnalyticsEvent extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      AnalyticsEvent.belongsTo(models.AnalyticsSession, {
        foreignKey: "id",
        sourceKey: "sessionId",
      });
    }
  }
  AnalyticsEvent.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      sessionId: {
        allowNull: false,
        foreignKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
        references: {
          model: "AnalyticsSession",
          key: "id",
        },
      },     
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "AnalyticsEvent",
      defaultScope: {},
    }
  );
  return AnalyticsEvent;
};
```

The query

```
const sessions = await AnalyticsSession.findAll({
    attributes: [
      "id",
    ],
    include: [
      {
        model: AnalyticsEvents,
        attributes: ["id"],
      },
    ],
    logging: console.log,
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indicate `sessionId` as a `foreignKey` option values because this field is a real foreign key field that points to `AnalyticsSession` in `AnalyticsEvent`:

```js
AnalyticsSession.hasMany(models.AnalyticsEvent, {
        foreignKey: "sessionId",
      });
...
AnalyticsEvent.belongsTo(models.AnalyticsSession, {
        foreignKey: "sessionId",
      });
```

The `sourceKey` by default is a primary key of 1 side in 1:N (i.e. a primary key of AnalyticsSession - `id` field)

Comment: That did the trick, although i'm not sure why. Do you only need to include the foreignKey from the child model in both?

Comment: Yes, exactly, because a primary key of the other side can be automatically detected from the model definition.